# Not able to install anything with brew

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, homebrew, carthage

I'm trying to install carthage with homebrew and I'm running with the below issue. Not only carthage, I'm unable to install any packages with brew.

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "carthage".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
userXXXXXX ~ % brew info carthage
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "carthage".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
```

I installed homebrew with
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
I tried uninstalling with below command to see if it rectifies the problem.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

and installed homebrew again but still got the same error.
On uninstall- I have got these messages. Is it safe to delete these files? Is this is the cause for other packages not getting installed?

```
Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/Frameworks/
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/McAfee/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/jamf/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/sbin/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

System configuration:
macOS Catalina - V 10.15.6
Xcode (11.0)
node : v10.14.1
When I run brew doctor, I get to see a lot of .h files with the below message.

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
```

Please help. I'm not sure what i have done wrong here.

Answer (score 5):

I used `brew doctor` And followed the suggested commands that were output by some warnings. And that did the trick!

Comment: It did work for me thanks

Comment: yes, this works. Follow the instructions from - brew doctor

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error uninstalling brew and deleting each folder created in the installation, check dir folder /usr/local.

Comment: Hi @pedro, Thanks for your answer. I already tried uninstalling and few under /usr/local wasn't deleted. I have mentioned the folder name in the description. 
Can i go ahead delete /usr/local/Homebrew/ - will that help?

Comment: I uninstalled brew and deleted all /usr/local/ content. My problem was any folder in /usr/local/ it was corrupted. I deleted all and í'll reinstall. It's working for me